# calling function to display html in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have this function in my `spinner.js` file:

```
import React from 'react';
import broomAndText from './ezgif.com-video-to-gif-3.gif';
import './spinner.css';

        function myGif() {
    
        return <html><body><div class="imgContainer"><img src={broomAndText} alt="broomAndText"/></div></body></html>

    }
    
    export default myGif;
```

I want to call this function from here:

```
 } else {

                        
       myGif()

        createCheckoutSession()
         console.log("does not exist!")
     }
   });
```

when I call myGif() like this, it does not display onto screen. how do i do this?

Comment: React is SPA which means whole components are running on a single web page. That means though many components are made, all components are put in a single .html file. That's why loading a page takes much less time on React. Seems other tags without HTML should be put.

Comment: Why html tag is used on a component?

Comment: @jacobkim React is absolutely not an SPA, it's a UI library. Whether you use it as an SPA, a server side rendered UI, or even just as a touch of reactivity in a plain HTML file is up to the user. Also, SPAs result in longer, far longer page loads, not shorter. That's the whole point. Longer startup, faster switching.

Comment: @rschristian React is not a simple UI library. When React is running the server which installed React is need. When SPA runs without a router module, switching within pages isn't possible. You shouldn't use React library only without many node packages.

Comment: React absolutely is just a UI library. There is no such thing as "React running the server". You absolutely can switch pages without a router module via anchor tags. They've existed for decades. It's how SSR works. There's no need to run React in an SPA. There's tons of ways to use it effectively.

Answer (score 1):

React components shouldn't render another `html` or `body` tag, it should be just the `div`. React components also use a `className` prop.

```
import React from 'react';
import broomAndText from './ezgif.com-video-to-gif-3.gif';
import './spinner.css';

function MyGif() {
  return (
    <div class="imgContainer">
      <img src={broomAndText} alt="broomAndText"/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default MyGif;
```

React components are also not called as functions, but rather they are templated into renderable JSX and the React framework handles calling the function during the component lifecycle.

```
import MyGif from '../path/to/MyGif";

...

return (
  ...
  <MyGif />
  ...
);
```